# Can a paratransit company refuse to reimburse you even if you had a medical situation?

Tags: civil-law, legal-research, litigation, oregon, disabilities

I'm asking on behalf of a friend of mine who is not on this site. They are blind and have a guide dog. We are both in Oregon, and we sometimes take the TriMet Lift paratransit service.

Last Sunday, my friend and their spouse, along with the guide dog were left stranded in the summer heat while waiting for the bus or cab to arrive. It was taking much longer than two hours. The dog started overheating and my friend, who is prediabetic, was beyond hungry.

Finally, the spouse ordered a Lyft to get back home. It was expensive, but what else could they do?

My friend's spouse asked the company the next morning to reimburse the cost of the Lyft ride, but they said that it was not their policy to do that, even under these circumstances.

Are they justified under state and federal law to say that?